# Grant permissions for a windows service

Tags: windows-10, permissions, user-accounts, windows-services

I am using windows 10. I have installed the SonicWall [NetExtender](https://www.sonicwall.com/products/remote-access/vpn-clients/) VPN Client. Looking in Services.msc I have two services added, the SonicWall Client Protection and SonicWall NetExtender Service. Although I am running Services as Admin user I am not able to start, stop or change the startup type of these services as the buttons are grayed out. How can I change this ? How can I grant a user the full permission to change the options of a service ?

What I tried so far:

- Right clicking on the .exe file → Properties → Security → Edit. This
  does not as the buttons Add and Remove are grayed out. I can see from
  here that a new created user sonicwall_client_protection_svc has the
  full control permissions.
- Right clicking on the .exe file → Properties → Security → Advanced. Change the Owner. This too does not work as I get the message "Unable to set new owner on NEService64.exe. Access denied." And changing the permissions from here is also not possible.
- With icacls command line. I am not sure if I did it correctly but I still got the message Access denied.

[image: Services NetExtender]

[image: exe file properties]

Comment: its not just any service, it is a security sensitive service. Antivirus and other security related products would be worthless if a piece of malware could just turn them off, so the are doing the only thing they can do to protect the system from malware; protect it's internals from access by you (since at a minimum, malware will have your level of privileged). you might be able to run a command prompt as system using psexec, and use the `sc` or `net stop` commands but I've encountered software that even `NT Authority\System` couldn't kill.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes I understand this but I want to grant access to the permissions from my Admin account. And then I want to stop this services as they should only run when needed.